# Kentor Auth Services integration with Okta

Tags: asp.net, saml-2.0, okta, kentor-authservices

I am using [Kentor Auth Services][1] [HttpModule][2] to integrate with our application using Okta as IdP. I can get the SampleApplication to work with Okta and when I try the same configuration through web.config after installing Kentor Auth Services through NuGet, nothing happens, just presented with the login screen to enter credentials even if I log into Okta and come to the app from there.

The Web.config is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
 <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup,     System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
<section name="system.identityModel.services" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelServicesSection, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
<section name="kentor.authServices" type="Kentor.AuthServices.Configuration.KentorAuthServicesSection, Kentor.AuthServices" />
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="Databasepsdb1" connectionString="Data Source=SQL_SERVER;Database=MYDATABASE;Trusted_Connection=no;User Id=USER_ID;Password=USER_PASSWORD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
<appSettings>
<add key="LogDatabaseCommands" value="false" />
<add key="LogDatabaseExceptions" value="default" />
<add key="LogCommitExceptions" value="default" />
<add key="TraceDatabaseCommands" value="false" />
<add key="TraceDataAccessMethods" value="false" />
<add key="TraceTransactionCache" value="false" />
<add key="ViewStateLocation" value="Page" />
<add key="WebServer" value="http://localhost" />
<add key="DefaultPageUrl" value="MyPages/MyPage.aspx" />
<add key="FCKeditor:BasePath" value="~/FCKeditor/" />
<add key="ApplicationName" value="MyPages" />
<add key="CookieEncryptionKey" value="SOME VALUE" />
<add key="URLEncryptionKey" value="SOME VALUE" />
<add key="LogEvents" value="false" />
<add key="ShowAutoSignInCheckBox" value="False" />
<add key="ShowRememberPasswordCheckBox" value="False" />
<add key="ShowRememberUserCheckBox" value="False" />
<add key="SignedOutPageUrl" value="Security/SignOut.aspx" />
<add key="SignInPageUrl" value="Security/SignIn.aspx" />
<add key="AuthenticationType" value="ProprietorySecurity" />
<add key="RoleManagement" value="ProprietoryRoles" />
<add key="SearchNestedGroups" value="False" />
<add key="SecurityDisabled" value="False" />
<add key="UserIdentityTable" value="My.App.Payslips.Business.UsersTable, App_Code" />
<add key="log4net.Config" value="log4net.config" />
<add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="True" />
<add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
 </appSettings>
 <system.web>
<roleManager enabled="false" cacheRolesInCookie="false" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" />
<siteMap defaultProvider="AspNetXmlSiteMapProvider" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<httpModules>
  <add name="AntiXssModule" type="Microsoft.Security.Application.SecurityRuntimeEngine.AntiXssModule" />
  <add name="ClaimsPrincipalHttpModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ClaimsPrincipalHttpModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</httpModules>
<pages validateRequest="false" theme="My.App">
  <namespaces>
    <clear />
    <add namespace="My.App.Payslips" />
    <add namespace="My.App.Payslips.UI" />
    <add namespace="My.App.Payslips.UI.Controls" />
    <add namespace="My.App.Payslips.Data" />
    <add namespace="My.App.Payslips.Business" />
    <add namespace="System" />
    <add namespace="System.Collections" />
    <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized" />
    <add namespace="System.Configuration" />
    <add namespace="System.Text" />
    <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" />
    <add namespace="System.Web" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Caching" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Security" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Profile" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.UI" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls" />
    <add namespace="BaseClasses" />
    <add namespace="BaseClasses.Web.UI.WebControls" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
  <tagMapping>
    <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompareValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.CompareValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0" />
    <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.CustomValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0" />
    <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RangeValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RangeValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0" />
    <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RegularExpressionValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RegularExpressionValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0" />
    <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RequiredFieldValidator" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.RequiredFieldValidator, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0" />
    <add tagType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.ValidationSummary" mappedTagType="Sample.Web.UI.Compatibility.ValidationSummary, Validators, Version=1.0.0.0" />
  </tagMapping>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
  </controls>
</pages>
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="Shared/Internal_Server_Error.html">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="Shared/Internal_Server_Error.html" />
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="Shared/Internal_Server_Error.html" />
</customErrors>
<authentication mode="Forms" />
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
<trace enabled="false" requestLimit="10" pageOutput="false" traceMode="SortByTime" localOnly="true" />
<sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=sa;password=" cookieless="false" timeout="60" />
<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-IE" uiCulture="en-IE" />
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" enableVersionHeader="false" executionTimeout="54000" />
<httpHandlers>
  <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
  <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<location path="DefaultWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx">
<system.web>
  <pages styleSheetTheme="" />
</system.web>
</location>
<system.net>
 <mailSettings>
     <smtp from="Server@domain.com">
    <network host="127.0.0.1" port="25" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
</system.net>
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0" />
    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
  </compiler>
  <!--
  <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
    <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.5.1" />
    <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true" />
    <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
  </compiler>
  -->
</compilers>
</system.codedom>
 <system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
 <modules>
  <remove name="ScriptModule" />
   <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="System.IdentityModel.Services.SessionAuthenticationModule, System.IdentityModel.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <add name="Saml2AuthenticationModule" type="Kentor.AuthServices.HttpModule.Saml2AuthenticationModule, Kentor.AuthServices.HttpModule" />
</modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
  <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
  <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
  <remove name="ScriptResource" />
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
</handlers>
 </system.webServer>
 <kentor.authServices entityId="https://subdomain.domain.com/aap1" returnUrl="https://subdomain.domain.com/aap1/" authenticateRequestSigningBehavior="Always">
<nameIdPolicy allowCreate="true" format="Persistent" />
<!--<requestedAuthnContext classRef="Password" comparison="Minimum" />-->
<identityProviders>
  <add entityId="http://www.okta.com/dfddusd45vad44fZ40h7" signOnUrl="https://dev-XXXXXX.oktapreview.com/app/MyAppdevXXXXXX_kentorauthserviceshttp_1/exk8dwyftyPFdCAZ40h7/sso/saml/" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" binding="HttpRedirect">
    <signingCertificate fileName="~/App_Data/okta.cer" />
  </add>
</identityProviders>
<!--    
<federations>
  <add metadataLocation="~/App_Data/okta_metadata.xml" allowUnsolicitedAuthnResponse="true" />
</federations>
-->    
 </kentor.authServices>
 <system.identityModel.services>
   <federationConfiguration>
  <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" name="SampleApplicationAuth" />
</federationConfiguration>
  </system.identityModel.services>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" appliesTo="v2.0.50727">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="AjaxControlToolkit" publicKeyToken="28f01b0e84b6d53e" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="4.1.40412.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="IKVM.Runtime" publicKeyToken="13235d27fcbfff58" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-0.42.0.6" newVersion="0.42.0.6" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.0.0.0" newVersion="5.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.2.0" newVersion="5.2.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Any help or direction will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

metadata

```
<EntityDescriptor ID="_b3b47928-45ab-43b2-ab66-c7469701ff73" entityID="https://subdomain.domain.com/aap1" cacheDuration="PT1H" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"><SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="true" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://subdomain.domain.com/aap1/AuthServices/Acs" index="0" isDefault="true" /><AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="https://subdomain.domain.com/aap1/AuthServices/Acs" index="1" isDefault="false" /></SPSSODescriptor></EntityDescriptor>
```

Comment: What happens if you try to access http://your-application/AuthServices? You should get a metadata document downloaded if the http module is properly loaded.

Comment: It allows me to down the metadata. I am editing to post Metadata above